# Python - Processing the data and analyse using functional programming

Tags: python

This is a straight forward question, How to use python to process the log file (Consider it as a json string for now). Below is the json data:

```
{
   "voltas": {
      "ac": [
         {
            "timestamp":1590761564,
            "is_connected":true,
            "reconnection_status":"N/A"
         },
         {
            "timestamp":1590761566,
            "is_connected":true,
            "reconnection_status":"N/A"
         },
         {
            "timestamp":1590761568,
            "is_connected":false,
            "reconnection_status":"true"
         },
         {
            "timestamp":1590761570,
            "is_connected":true,
            "reconnection_status":"N/A"
         },
         {
            "timestamp":1590761572,
            "is_connected":true,
            "reconnection_status":"N/A"
         },
         {
            "timestamp":1590761574,
            "is_connected":false,
            "reconnection_status":"false"
         },
         {
            "timestamp":1590761576,
            "is_connected":false,
            "reconnection_status":"true"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Since the question is just regarding how to process the json data, I am skipping the discussion about the data in json. Now, what I need is the analysed data as below.

```
{ 
    "voltas" : [
        "ac": {
            "number_of_actual_connection_drops": 3,
            "time_interval_between_droppings": [4, 8],
            "number_of_successful_reconnections": 2,
            "number_of_failure_reconnections": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how the data is analysed:

**"number_of_actual_connection_drops":** Number of "is_connected" == false.

**"time_interval_between_droppings":** It is a list which will be populated from the end(append from beginning). We need to pick the time stamp of the item which will have  "is_connected":false, and "reconnection_status":"true". In this case last(7th item) block with timestamp =  **1590761576**. Now we need fo find the timestamp of previous block with "is_connected":false, and "reconnection_status":"true". In this case it's 3rd item with timestamp **1590761568**. Now the last item in the list is difference of this timestamps 8. Now the list is `[8]`.

Now the timestamp is **1590761568** and we don't have any previous block with `is_connected: false`, and `reconnection_status: true`, so we will take the first items timestamp which is **1590761564** and now the difference is 4. So the list is `[4, 8]`

**"number_of_successful_reconnections":** Number of "reconnected_status" = true

**"number_of_failure_connections":** Number of "reconnected_status" = false

We can achieve this with for loops and some if conditions. I am interested in doing this using functional programming ways (reduce, map, filter) in python.

For simplification I have mentioned only "ac". There will be many items similar to this. Thanks.

Comment: I am familiar with java streams but not sure about the python equivalent. Any leads are much appreciable. thanks!

Comment: The data in the result (the analysed json) is what I care about. We are flexible to change the design(structure) of the json input.

Comment: Your definition for `number_of_actual_connection_drops` does not match the expected output. Perhaps you meant "number of true-to-false transitions in `is_connected`"?

Comment: @MustafaAydın I will edit and change that to 3. It should be actually 2 but its difficult to explain here.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Yes. it actually means the true droppings. By theory it is equivalent to "number_of_successful_reconnections"